# Interactions with "former friends" on Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline, facebook-notifications

I'm wondering whether you get notified on interactions with items relating to you if you can't see the item anymore on that user's profile on Facebook.

My specific case is that I posted a message on user A's Timeline a long time ago but I've deleted them from my Friends list since then. The user has set their posts to be visible to "Friends except Acquaintances".

Will I get notified if someone "likes" and/or comments on my post on user A's Timeline, or do I not receive notifications anymore because user A is no longer my friend?